# Do we need to have the Browser installed on GUI less RedHat Linux m/c when we are running headless tests using XVFB?

Tags: serenity-bdd, serenity-js

Since we are facing problems with running headless Serenity tests using the installed Firefox browser on a Jenkins Server running on RedHat Linux machine, we installed XVFB to run the tests.

Our preferred browser to test is with Chrome, not Firefox. But Chrome is not available for RedHat Linux (Jenkins) Server.

Question, is do we need to have the Chrome browser installed on the Linux machine in order to run headless tests using XVFB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have both the chrome browser and chrome driver to run tests. You can find the chrome driver [here][http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads]. If Chrome is not available for Red Hat Edition, you can install open source chromium.